# Get list of addresses added to a PHPMailer object

Tags: php, phpmailer

How can I get a list of email addresses that have been added to to PHPMailer with its addAddress($email_address) method?

Answer (score 1):

It always helps to [read the docs](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer-PHPMailer-PHPMailer.html#method_getToAddresses). The method you need is `getToAddresses`, which will give you all the `to` addresses:

```
$toAddresses = $mail->getToAddresses();
```

Also note the existence of related methods for cc, bcc, and all addresses.

Comment: OP doesn't ask about clearing anything.

Comment: You're quite right - I had windows open on two different questions and answered the wrong one here! Nevertheless, the info is in exactly the same doc, answer updated.